# Which version of MS Report Reviewer should I install on Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: reporting-services

Moving one application from windows 2003 server to windows 2008 R2. The application uses Microsoft Report Viewer. After publishing the application and when I browse the web application, I get an error with web.config stating the Microsoft reviewer is not available. Will it be okay to download Report Reviewer 2005 redisrtibutables for consistency with what was installed on the older server, or should I install the latest Report Reviewer which is the 2010 SP1 version. Please let me know. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Either option should be okay but the 2010 report viewer is a huge improvement and works really well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Thought I would be limited to the latest 2010 version of Report Viewer redistributable on a  windows 2008 R2 server.  Instead of changing the web.config for the lines referencing the report viewer and it's guid and version, I installed the 2008 reportviewer redistributable install on the server - all is good. Thanks,